# Find most recent duplicates ID with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I use to do

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS occurences
FROM wineries
GROUP BY email
HAVING (COUNT(email) > 1);
```

to find duplicates based on their email.

But now I'd need their ID to be able to define which one to remove exactly.

The second constraint is: I want only the LAST INSERTED duplicates.

So if there's 2 entries with test@test.com as an email and their IDs are respectively 40 and 12782 it would delete only the 12782 entry and keep the 40 one.

Any ideas on how I could do this? I've been mashing SQL for about a hour and can't seem to find exactly how to do this.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Is the ID numeric and in order?  Is record 231 always after record 32?

Comment: Good question: yes it is. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Possible (ahem) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612918/mysql-delete-older-duplicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you sort of answer your question.  You seem to want `max(id)`:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) AS occurences, max(id)
FROM wineries
GROUP BY email
HAVING (COUNT(email) > 1);
```

You can delete the others using the statement.  Delete with `join` has a tricky syntax where you have to list the table name first and then specify the `from` clause with the join:

```
delete wineries
            from wineries join
            (select email, max(id) as maxid
             from wineries
             group by email
             having count(*) > 1
            ) we
            on we.email = wineries.email and
               wineries.id < we.maxid;
```

Or writing this as an `exists` clause:

```
delete from wineries
    where exists (select 1
                  from (select email, max(id) as maxid
                        from wineries
                        group by email
                       ) we
                  where we.email = wineries.email and wineries.id < we.maxid
                 )
```

Comment: First one: `delete from wineries w join (select email, max(winery_id) as maxid from wineries group by email having count(*) > 1 ) we on we.email = w.email and we.winery_id < maxid;` gives me: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'w join (select email, max(winery_id) as maxid from wineries group by email havin' at line 10

Comment: Second one: `delete from wineries where exists (select 1 from (select email, max(winery_id) as maxid from wineries group by email ) we where we.email = wineries.email and we.winery_id < maxid)` gives me: Unknown column 'we.winery_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thanks for responding and for suggesting more than one solution.

Comment: I also forgot to mention, email should NOT be null. Because null passes as a duplicate and all of those that have NO email gets deleted. Could I simply add a `WHERE email IS NOT NULL` between the from wineries and the group by?

Answer (score 1):

```
select email, max(id), COUNT(email) AS occurences
FROM wineries
GROUP BY email
HAVING (COUNT(email) > 1);
```

Comment: This will only delete the most recent inserted id where there are duplicates. if there are 3+ records with the same email he would still have dupes.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from wineries
where id not in
(
  select * from 
  ( 
     select min(id)
     from wineries
     group by email
  ) x
)
```

You need a subquery to trick MySQL to delete from a table it is selecting from at the same time.

Comment: What if an entry has NO duplicates? will they get deleted since the query won't get them? Oh I guess the group by will still fetch the one with nothing to group with?

Comment: No, since you select the lowest ids and don't delete them (`where id not in`) - entries without duplicates are save.

Comment: Doing so: `select * from wineries
where winery_id not in
(
  select * from 
  ( 
     select min(winery_id)
     from wineries
     group by email
  ) x
)` to check what will get deleted actually gave me a list of the recent ones instead of the latest ones. Is it normal?

Comment: Are you sure you got the latest entries with that query? `min(id)` will get the lowest `id`.

Comment: He is deleting ids that are not in that list. So this will delete ALL ids that are not the first id found for any email. The select * from level subquery is not needed in this, and aliasing it will cause an error here.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE duplicates.*
FROM wineries
JOIN wineries AS duplicates USING (email)
WHERE duplicates.id < wineries.id;
```

*[play with it on sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be4bd/6)*

Comment: The OP is wanting to delete the newest entered ids and keep the first. This answer will only keep the newest id inserted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest option:

```
DELETE FROM wineries
 WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM wineries
GROUP BY email 
);
```

This will only keep the first inserted record for each email address, all other records will be deleted. Credit for this answer should go to @juergen d since this is just a revised version of his answer.