# SELECT DUPLICATE MAX(ID)

Tags: mysql

I have data similar to the following in my table:

```
id       territory_id       platform_id         title_id    other columns
1        US                 ITUNES              155         10 others columns...
100      US                 ITUNES              155         10 others columns...
101      FR                 ITUNES              155         10 others columns...
```

I need to `SELECT MAX(ID)` on all duplicate rows, based on `(territory_id, platform_id, title_id)`.

The query on the above data set should return the id `100`, since the only duplicate above based on `(territory_id, platform_id, title_id)` is `('US', 'ITUNES', 155)` and the `MAX(ID)` of that duplicate entry is `100` (not `1`).

How would I build this query? So far I have:

```
SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY territory_id, platform_id, title_id
```

Comment: `SELECT territory_id, platform_id,title_id,MAX(id) FROM my_table GROUP BY territory_id, platform_id,title_id;`

Comment: This has GOT to be a duplicate question and I can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find most recent duplicates ID with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618415/find-most-recent-duplicates-id-with-mysql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` the 3 fields, then using `HAVING` clause you can identify duplicates. Using `MAX` you can get the max `ID` for each of those groups having duplicates:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), territory_id, platform_id, title_id
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY territory_id, platform_id, title_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da0f4/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

select DISTINCT territory_id,  max(ID)
  ,platform_id,title_id
  from test t
  GROUP BY territory_id,platform_id,title_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

Here are the results from the replicated table
territory_id    id  platform_id title_id
US          100         ITUNES      155

If you needed to you could go one step further and declare a variable if this will make its way to a report.