# MySQL choose one field in duplicated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users rights. These rights can be Write or Read. I have a SQL view which merges profile_user table and right_user table. This view give me the following results:

```
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| email | right     | write_or_read |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| admin | dashboard | write         |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| admin | dashboard | read          |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| admin | log       | read          |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

How can I un-duplicate dashboard write to get only the most important (the write right).
I want to write an SQL query which gives me the following result:

```
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| admin | dashboard | write         |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| admin | log       | read          |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618415/find-most-recent-duplicates-id-with-mysql) but the answer covers only id numeric field to get the right record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression to list the conditions in priority. This works for more than two values as well:

```
SELECT email, right, CASE
    WHEN SUM(write_or_read = 'write') > 0 THEN 'write'
    WHEN SUM(write_or_read = 'read')  > 0 THEN 'read'
    -- more conditions
END AS permission
FROM t
GROUP BY email, right
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a very clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a simple `max()` works:

```
select email, right, max(write_or_read)
from user_rights
group by email, right;
```

Comment: Waouh... it was so simple... Thank you :)

Comment: This option works currently but isn't very scale-able. It only works if "rights" happen to always be in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: Let me rephrase that... If priority of "rights" always happen to be in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: Yes, thank you for advice. I will pay attention to don't use this with other terms.

Comment: @drakin8564 . . . There are only two "rights" in this example, so either `min()` or `max()` will work.  Hence, it seems like the simplest and best solution.  For multiple strings, a different method would be used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wanted to make sure that they were aware that this may break if they ever add another "right" to the list. If their are 2 options, more often than not there is potential for more than 2 options. I will agree that it is the simplest solution and it will work given the current scenario. I do not agree that it is the best solution since it is also fragile. The best solution would be having an integer column(instead of text) on the user_rights table that maps to a dictionary table containing the definitions of the rights and a numeric column used for prioritization of those rights.